# Elastic Search Unique Records

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently I am Working on Elastic Search, I need unique records, and my mySql Query is `select practice_area_name from practiceareas`

And also I tried Below through some elastic references, and my code is

```
"query" => array(
                "filtered" => array(
                    "query" => array("match_all" => array())
                )
            ),
            "aggs" => array(
                "practiceareas" => array(
                    "terms" => array(
                        "field" => "practice_area_name",
                        "size" => 0
                    )
                )
            )
```

Here practiceareas are type in my elastic index and practice_area_name is field.
I Got Same Result, like below

"practice_areas":[{"practice_area_id"
:"237","practice_area_name":"Anemia","vendors_count":"26","practice_area_Count":1},{"practice_area_id"
:"237","practice_area_name":"Anemia","vendors_count":"26","practice_area_Count":1},{"practice_area_id"
:"237","practice_area_name":"Anemia","vendors_count":"26","practice_area_Count":1}]

Duplicate results are coming.

Comment: Is it a typo? Should "filed" be "field"?

Comment: sorry.. it is field only

Comment: Please share your mapping of the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get records count

by name wise

`GET  practice_areas/area/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "Name" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "practice_area_name.keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}`

[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCnzZ.png)